# How to save file content into flash at compile time using IDE

Tags: c, stm32cubeide

I've been using ESP-IDF for quite some time and there is default option to use text file as a version provider. Which is compiled into a code and available at runtime.

1. I wish to do the same on STM32, so whenever I change the file content (which is project version string "v0.000") its gonna be compiled into FLASH section that I've created.

version.txt

```
    v0.000
```

2. I wanted to include that file using symbols but I just dont know how to...

- [image: -d]
- All Iam getting is the PATH to file. Maybe there is a way to use that path, to read from file at this point?

3. For now I am convering string into a word (uint32) and specify that in my main.c

main.c

```
    const uint32_t version[] __attribute__((section(".version"))) = {
        0xC0FEBABE, 0x76302E30, 0x30300000
    };
```

FLASH

```
    .version :
    {
        KEEP(*(.version))
    } >FLASH
```

Comment: Can you change the content of the file to hold a C string literal including the quotes: `"v0.000"` ? Then you could just do something like `const char version[] __attribute__((section(".version"))) = \r #include "version.txt" \r ;`

Comment: It's often a sensible solution to run a script pre-compilation which generates the .c source file. All IDEs should support this so it's a fairly portable way of solving the problem, without dragging all manner of platform-specific tricks into your source and/or linker script.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry for late response, I have used your solution but it functions as a workaround. It's becouse I need 0xC0FEBABE to be written at compilation time. Usint your way All I get is an ASCII string

Comment: I've just added `const uint32_t version[] __attribute__((section(".version"))) = 0xC0FEBABE` to my code after include version.txt (noted that compilator needs correct order) And there goes a question. Is this relevant ? and certain ?